# How to pass a type to a method?

Tags: c#

How can I call this constructor ?

```
public class DataField
{
    public String Name;
    public Type TheType;
    public DataField(string name, Type T)
    {
        Name = name;
        TheType = T;
    }
}
```

I thought of

```
f = new DataField("Name",typeof(new String()));
```

but I want to avoid object creation.
So is this one ok ?

```
f = new DataField("Name",String);
```

Comment: What does the compiler say?

Comment: What do you want to do with TheType? Maybe you can use generics?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a type name with `typeof`:

```
f = new DataField("Name", typeof(string));
```

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to use simply `typeof(string)`

Answer (score -2):

Passing `String.class` should work. It's an instance of `Class`, which implements `Type`:

```
new DataField("Name", String.class);
```

Comment: @CodeIgnoto: I believe that Alexey mean to pass String to the typeof function, he just hasn't made it very clear. Alexey... make it more clear!

Comment: i didnt down vote but how can you pass a class name.you need a Type instance in this case which is only possible through a typeOf or GetType

Comment: Sorry, I meant `String.class`. Updated the answer.

Comment: OK... now you are definitely off target. What is `string.class`? It doesn't exist!

Comment: `X.class` is the syntax to refer to the `Class` object for class `X`. I'm a little confused about your lowercase `string`. The standard `String` class in Java starts with an uppercase letter.